# NumPy Simultaneous Equation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm solving simultaneous equations using NumPy
and this is the code I used to solve `10x+y=33` and `11x+y=36` this should result in `x=3` and `y=3`

```
A = np.array([[10, 1], [11, 1]])
B = np.array([33, 36])
C = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
print(C)
```

but when I `print(C)` which is an array containing the value of `x,y` ,

```
[3. 3.]
```

gets printed as a result and when I print the values individually say `print(C[0])` and `print(C[1])`,

then `3.0000000000000067` and `2.9999999999999316` get printed

Why are these values printed instead of `[3,3]`
What can I do to get the values as `[3,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

round() is made for you. haha

```
print(round(C[0], 5))
```

**5** means that you want to round to the nearest 10^5

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is returning float values to you (with high precision), you have to change them yourself, but saving them with float precision is not bad either, it can be useful in calculations and other stuff, but to show them to users, you can always format them and print the variable values with nth decimal accuracy! I attached a sample code!

### Sample Code:

```
print("X:{:.2f} Y:{:.2f}".format(x, y))
```

#### Edit: AS OP quoted, the variable can be into two or three decimal places, so I updated the code now!!!

Comment: but in some other equation if I had x=7.4 and y=8.3 then int would make them 7 and 8 right?

Comment: @NePtUnE in that case you have to roundoff your variables to required decimal places! And yes, int will make them 7 and 8 cuz it has no way of storing decimal numbers

Comment: For healty practices, you can always store that float values inside variables and print users formatted variable values, it will do your task of both using the variables later and showing users a nicely formatted values